# Oracle Update Query Data masking for column

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, security

i tried to Update one column with Datamasking using `standard_hash()` on Oracle Sql, but while doing with millions of records it takes a long time to update as standard_hash(column). Can someone give the solution or suggestions for tuning the update query?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: ya actually we are refreshing DB from One Environment to other environment, so sensitive information needs to to hidden ..

Comment: ...OK, but if this be a one time thing, why does performance even matter to you?

Comment: It took long time to update the column, so im asking anyother way to do that?

Comment: How long is a long time? What wait events are hit and for how long? Is the column included in indexes? How large is the table (in GBs and rows)? How exactly are you currently doing the update?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, this is just my guess but consider the scenario where dev/test environments are routinely refreshed from production using Delphix or some other cloning technology, and new data protection rules require personal details to be obfuscated. Updating columns in a large system may take weeks and require additional storage if the tables are compressed. I don't have a solution and I am just hoping this does not come to my current project.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating every row in a big table. That will take time. Because you're updating every row there's no way to speed up the access path assuming your DBAs have done a good job of configuring the database for efficient multi-block reads.  (Indexes are likely to be useless, unless the columns you're encrypting are indexed.)

The task you are doing - hashing values - is computationally expensive. That will take time. How much time depends on the strength of the encryption you've chosen and the length of the columns you're encrypting. Encrypting a 4000 character string takes more time than a 16 character string. Using SHA-512 takes more time than using MD5.

You're probably not worried about hash collisions with this task, so if you have the opportunity to switch algorithms go for MD5. (To be fair, even MD5 has an acceptably low possibility of hash collision, it's just higher than the stronger levels of SHA.

Alternatively, do you actually need to use encryption? Could you get away with replacing the data with DBMS_RANDOM values? I know there are use cases for encryption, when we need the repeatability of hashing, but it's worth asking the question.

In short, you are undertaking a computationally expensive operation on a big table. It will take time. For a one-off exercise you should probably just live with it. Only consider performance tuning if this turns into a regular process.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, I found solution i used CTAS query to Create Dummy table with Standard_hash and later i renamed the table... For 35 million records it took only 8 minutes but simple update method took around 1hr to update row by Row